# What is the correct way to use a PyTorch Module inside a PyTorch Function?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, automatic-differentiation

We have a custom [`torch.autograd.Function`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function) `z(x, t)` which computes an output `y` in a way not amenable to direct automatic differentiation, and have computed the Jacobian of the operation with respect to its inputs `x` and `t`, so we can implement the `backward` method.

However, the operation involves making several internal calls to a neural network, which we have implemented for now as a stack of `torch.nn.Linear` objects, wrapped in `net`, a `torch.nn.Module`. Mathematically, these are parameterized by `t`.

Is there any way that we can have `net` itself be an input to the `forward` method of `z`? Then, we would return from our `backward` the list of products of the upstream gradient `Dy` and parameter Jacobia `dydt_i`, one for each of the parameters `ti` that are children of `net` (in addition to `Dy*dydx`, although x is data and does not need gradient accumulation).

Or do we really instead need to take `t` (actually a list of individual `t_i`), and reconstruct internally in `z.forward` the actions of all the `Linear` layers in `net`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could create a custom functor that inherits `torch.autograd.Function` and make the `forward` and `backward` methods non-static (i.e remove the `@staticmethod` in [this example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html) so that `net` could be an attribute of your functor. that would look like

```
class MyFunctor(torch.nn.autograd.Function):
    def __init(net):
         self.net = net
    
     def forward(ctx, x, t):
         #store x and t in ctx in the way you find useful
         # not sure how t is involved here
         return self.net(x) 

     def backward(ctx, grad):
         # do your backward stuff

net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(...), ...)
z = MyFunctor(net)
y = z(x, t)
```

This will yield a warning that you are using a deprecated legacy way of creating autograd functions (because of the non-static methods), and you need to be extra careful with zeroing the gradients in `net`after having backpropagated. So not really convenient, but I am not aware of any better way to have a stateful autograd function.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. If you simply try to call a `Function` like you would a `Module`, the deprecation is raised as a `RuntimeError` (in PyTorch 1.6 and 1.7, at least).

Comment: More relevantly, though we do not list `net` as an input to `forward`, we still will need the VJP between `grad` and all the Jacobian `dz_dtheta` (where each `theta` is a parameter of `net`). But PyTorch is only expecting two outputs from `backward`, because we gave two inputs to `forward`.

Comment: It gets worse, too: even if you write the signature as `forward(x, t, *thetas)` and therefore expect 2+`len(thetas)` VJP outputs from `backward`, you need to actually *use* thetas in `backward` in order to get correct gradients. Unlike, say, TensorFlow, the parameters of `net` are not global variables, since PyTorch is define-by-run. This is my problem to solve internally to `backward`, but i think I need a function `net(x, *thetas)` that reconstructs the `forward` of the `Module` as an explicit function of `thetas`.

Comment: well then I'm sorry, I don't have any smarter idea in stock. you should probably try to ask on pytorch forum, the devs may have a solution

Comment: At first, I thought there might be [a way](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/f4f73eb15f4be741b314678b87e62de4) by calling `forward` on the `Function` directly rather than `__call__` (the `Module` way) or `apply` (the `Function`) way. But then I realized that without the `@staticmethod`, PyTorch was ignoring my `backward` implementation and just doing normal operator overloading. My current approach is to use [`Module.load_state_dict`](https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/f4f73eb15f4be741b314678b87e62de4) to create the closure without having to throw away the `Module` completely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar, where the static restrictions on PyTorch functions are cumbersome. Similar in spirit to trialNerror's answer, I instead keep the PyTorch function methods static and pass in functions for them to use, which gets around the issues with making the functor non-static:

```py
class NonStaticBackward(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, backward_fn, input):
        ctx.backward_fn = backward_fn
        # ... do other stuff
        return input

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        # Call into our non-static backward function

        # Since we passed in the backward function as input, 
        # PyTorch expects a placeholder grad for it. 
        return None, ctx.backward_fn(ctx, grad_output)
```

Passing in the backwards function every time gets annoying, so I usually wrap it:

```py
def my_non_static_backward(ctx, grad_output):
    print("Hello from backward!")
    return grad_output

my_fn = lambda x: NonStaticBackward.apply(my_non_static_backward, x)

y = my_fn(Tensor([1, 2, 3]))
```

This way, you can write the grad function somewhere where it has access to what it needs: no need to pass `net`.